# What is this component? D5SV17

Tags: components

What is this component?

Can someone link me to an equivalent replacement, haven't been able to find anything

D5SV17

[image: D5SV17]

Comment: Sometimes SMT parts are hard to track down by what's printed on them alone, it might be worth adding a few details on what it's from and if you have thoughts on what it might be based on the location and what it connects to.

Comment: it appears to be being used as a three-terminal device (4pins are connected to the large plane)

Comment: might be a dual transistor, might be a voltage reference.

Answer (score 3):

The massive planes and the small tap off of the gate suggest a switching power supply design, so I assumed a power MOSFET.  The Q on the silkscreen is another telling sign.  This marking chart looks much the same, note the line over the year and week.

[image]

In addition this pinout looks about right to the usage.  The only confusion is the capacitor between gate and source.  A little bit of context might help that.  Hope this helps.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if forced to guess i'd say it's probably a dual transistor with only one half being used. there;s no other way I can explain its use as a 3 terminal device and the capacitor across pins 3 and 4, also Q in the silkscreen suggests a transistor

Comment: It is from a laptop. Photo taken from working board. The broken board its completely blown. I'll replace with a 6 pin MOSFET and see how I go

Answer (score 0):

Possible candidate with a D5 suffix:

Rohm General Purpose (dual digital transistors)

http://www.s-manuals.com/pdf/datasheet/e/m/emd5%2C_umd5n_rohm.pdf